# How to switch icon when containing class 'active' in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, routerlink, routerlinkactive

I have a bottom navbar with icons. How can when the router-link has class 'active' it will turn into an active icon? Default icon 1 is active.

```
  <li>
   <router-link v-if="active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 1 active
    </router-link>
    <router-link v-if="!active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 1
    </router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
   <router-link v-if="active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 2 active
    </router-link>
    <router-link v-if="!active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 2
    </router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
   <router-link v-if="active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 3 active
    </router-link>
    <router-link v-if="!active" :class="{active}" active-class="active">
      Icon 3
    </router-link>
  </li>
```

Comment: It it unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Binding the HTML class:

```
  <li>
    <router-link @click="isActive1 = true" :class="{ active: isActive1 }">
      Icon 1
    </router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <router-link @click="isActive2 = true" :class="{ active: isActive2 }">
      Icon 2
    </router-link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <router-link @click="isActive3 = true" :class="{ active: isActive3 }">
      Icon 3 Active
    </router-link>
  </li>
```

Implement **isActive** variables:

```
data: {
   isActive1: true, // default icon1 
   isActive2: false,
   isActive3: false,
 }
```

And implement **watchers**:

```
watch: {
  isActive1(val) {
    if(val === true) {
      this.isActive2 = false
      this.isActive3 = false
    }
  },
  isActive2(val) {
    if(val === true) {
      this.isActive1 = false
      this.isActive3 = false
    }
  },
  isActive3(val) {
    if(val === true) {
      this.isActive1 = false
      this.isActive2 = false
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html